# How to call MATLAB library from Python virtual environment on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, matlab-deployment, python-venv

I am trying to call a MATLAB package packaged for Python on macOS from a virtual environment.

In order to use the MATLAB runtime on macOS, the [`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` must be updated to point to the MATLAB Runtime](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/python/install-a-matlab-compiler-sdk-python-package.html) as well as `libpython3.6.dylib`.

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/runtime/maci64:/Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/sys/os/maci64:/Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/bin/maci64:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

Then create and activate a Python virtual environment:

```
$ python3.6 -m venv py36
$ source py36/bin/activate
```

Next install the [MATLAB packaged for Python application](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-python-application-with-matlab-code.html) into the virtual environment:

```
(py36) $ cd /Applications/my_matlab_app/application
(py36) $ python setup.py install
(py36) $ pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- -------
matlabruntimeforpython R2018b 
pip                    18.1   
setuptools             40.6.2
```

Now attempt to run a script that imports your MATLAB library within the virtual environment:

```
(py36) $ python matlab_test.py 
Exception caught during initialization of Python interface. Details: On the Mac, use 'mwpython' rather than 'python' to start a script or session that will call deployed MATLAB code from Python.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matlab_test.py", line 26, in <module>
    import my_matlab_app
  File "/Users/user/venv/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/my_matlab_app/__init__.py", line 283, in <module>
    _pir.import_cppext()
  File "/Users/user/venv/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/my_matlab_app/__init__.py", line 276, in import_cppext
    self.cppext_handle = importlib.import_module("matlabruntimeforpython" + self.interpreter_version)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
RuntimeError: On the Mac, use 'mwpython' rather than 'python' to start a script or session that will call deployed MATLAB code from Python.
```

The problem is that as far as I can tell, [`mwpython`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/python/mwpython.html) can't be used within virtual environments. Is there a way to work around this? We're currently struggling making repeatable environments because `mwpython` seems to hard code everything to be globally installed.

Tested on:

- macOS 10.14.2
- Python 3.6.8 installed from python.org
- MATLAB Runtime 2018b

Answer (score 1):

The activate script unsets PYTHONHOME and sets VIRTUAL_ENV, which is the folder path to your virtual environment. mwpython will use the python interpreter pointed to by PYTHONHOME (assuming it is a supported version, of course). So, you merely need to set and export PYTHONHOME to VIRTUAL_ENV before calling mwpython, e.g.

```
python3.6 -m venv py36
source py36/bin/activate

export PYTHONHOME=$VIRTUAL_ENV
mwpython matlab_test.py
```